# Using static mutex in a class

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, boost

I have a class that I can have many instances of. Inside it creates and initializes some members from a 3rd party library (that use some global variables) and is not thread-safe.

I thought about using static boost::mutex, that would be locked in my class constructor and destructor. Thus creating and destroying instances among my threads would be safe for the 3rd party members.

```
class MyClass

{
  static boost::mutex mx;

  // 3rd party library members
public:
  MyClass();
  ~MyClass();
};

MyClass::MyClass()
{
  boost::mutex::scoped_lock scoped_lock(mx);
  // create and init 3rd party library stuff
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
  boost::mutex::scoped_lock scoped_lock(mx);
  // destroy 3rd party library stuff
}
```

I cannot link because I receive error:

```
undefined reference to `MyClass::mx`
```

1. Do I need some special initialization of such static member?
2. **Is there anything wrong about using static mutex?**

**Edit:**  Linking problem is fixed with correct definition in cpp

```
boost::mutex MyClass::mx;
```

Comment: If you use a static mutex, you will serialize the use of *all* the instances of your class, completely negating any benefit you may gain through multithreading.  Are you sure you want this?

Comment: @John Dibling 
Yes, only creating and destroying the objects will be protected - it will not happen too often. The rest of the time the instances will be used without locking the mutex and it should be quite efficient.

Comment: @Dmity: Which leads me to my next question: are you sure it will be safe to use the instances without locking?

Comment: @John Dibling The 3rd party library provide some locking mechanism that's supposed to guaranty thread-safe work, but they need existing objects - my tests showed that it's working. It seems though that concurrent creating of these objects in not very safe.

Comment: Remember that a `static` data member of a `class` will be shared among all instances of the class *AND* instances of derived classes.  You may want to reconsider the `static` qualifier.

Comment: @Thomas I'm aware of it, that's exactly what I want and I'm not planning to derive this class. Using this static mutex seems like the easiest solution comparing to Factory for example.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You have declared, but not defined your class static mutex. Just add the line

```
boost::mutex MyClass::mx;
```

to the cpp file with the implementation of MyClass.

Comment: 10x, it did fix the linking problem. I tried defining it before but missed the type before MyClass::mx

Comment: Why is this required? and what is the difference between declaration and definition?

Answer (score 3):

The question was made a long time ago but merely to update the post, now you can use [`inline variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline):

```
inline static std::mutex mx;
```

that does the ODR rule, solving those linkage problems.

**UPDATE**

Yep, as @isudfv pointed out, it's available since C++17.

Comment: [since c++17 ](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline)