# How do you share a mutex among different instances of a class?

Tags: c++, boost, synchronization, condition-variable, boost-mutex

I was wondering how to share a mutex in one class amongst different instances of another class.

Right now, I have a class, Indexer, that has a Boost mutex and condition_variable as private member variables. I create an auto_ptr of the Indexer class in my main and pass a pointer of Indexer to instances of another class, Robot.

I do that like the following:

```
std::auto_ptr<Indexer> index_service(new Indexer());
Robot a(*index_service.get());
Robot b(*index_service.get());
Robot c(*index_service.get());
```

Robot's constructor is:

```
Robot(Indexer &index_service)
{
  this->index_service = index_service;
}
```

Robot's header looks like:

```
class Robot
{
   public:
     Robot(Indexer &index_service);
   private:
     Indexer index_service;
};
```

However, since mutexes are noncopyable, I get an error.

I was thinking of making the mutex and condition_variable shared_ptrs but I read that this could result in unexpected behaviour.

Can someone please show me the proper/correct way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: I think in your Robot class you mean to have a variable of type Indexer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a C++ guru, but it seems like the unholy mix of pass by reference and pointers is trouble here.

Specifically you do this: `this->index_service = index_service;` 
But the value is passed in as `Indexer &index_service`
And since the local index_service is type `Indexer index_service;` 
I believe that the assignment implies copy.

I assume you only want one instance of the `Indexer`, so you are really meaning to store a reference to it in your Robot class. To do that you would want to have your constructer take a pointer (which is what the `*index_service.get()` call is getting you anyway). Further you want your class variable to be a pointer type.

Comment: This seems to have worked out, thanks! I need to go back over some of my code and make sure I'm not making local copies... After doing this, I needed to change it to index_service.get()

Comment: Ah yes, that would make sense. My statement "which is what the *index_service.get() call is getting you anyway" is wrong... That would de-ref the return of get (giving you the object) which is fine if your constructor is pass by reference because c++ does the magic for you...

Answer (score 0):

Declare a static boost::mutex in your class. Remember to define it in your .cpp file.

Check here:
[Using static mutex in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462961/using-static-mutex-in-a-class)

Answer (score 0):

Just as another option you can use `std::shared_ptr` in place of `std::auto_ptr` and in your `Robot` class change `Indexer to`std::shared_ptr`.

```
class Robot
{
public:
    Robot( std::shared_ptr<Indexer> const &index_service)
    {
        this->index_service = index_service;
}
private:
   std::shared_ptr<Indexer> index_service;
};

std::shared_ptr<Indexer> index_service(new Indexer());
Robot a(*index_service.get());
Robot b(*index_service.get());
Robot c(*index_service.get());
```